# How can I get the latest files from a Unix server to another Unix server?

Tags: unix, sftp

How can I get the only the latest files from a Unix server to another Unix server?

I have connected via SFTP to server 2 and trying to apply a for loop to check the time stamp, which is not working:

```
sftp $SERVER2  << !EOF
cd $Server2_FILE_LOCATION
echo Pwd File location: $pwd

LastUpdatedTS=$(grep "value of TimeStamp is" /root/airtelSnD/BoTreeScript/BotreeLastFileTS.txt | cut -d'=' -f2)

echo 1

for file in mad_*.*
do
CurrentFileTS=$(stat -c %Y $file |awk '{print  strftime( "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", $1 )}')

echo 2

echo TS of last updated file is : $LastUpdatedTS
echo value CurrentFileTS is $CurrentFileTS

echo 3

if [[ $CurrentFileTS -gt $LastUpdatedTS ]]
 then
    echo if......
    mget  $file $DESTINATION_SERVER
    echo value of TimeStamp is=$CurrentFileTS > $LASTFILE_TS    
else
    echo else...       
 fi
done

quit
!EOF
```

Comment: I agree with the posted answers that you should use a tool that is designed to do this task.  But if you want to know how to get scripts _like this_ to work, try putting a backslash before all dollar sign symbols except for the ones that are using a value from the `sftp` environment.  (It looks like `$Server2_FILE_LOCATION` and `$DESTINATION_SERVER` are the only ones to which that applies.)

Comment: bolD's answer to the following question might interest you:
[scp-without-replacing-existing-files-in-the-destination](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14191/scp-without-replacing-existing-files-in-the-destination)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)?

> rsync is an open source utility that provides fast incremental file transfer.

It will only transfer changed/new files, and only deltas for changed files.  It also has various other [nifty features](http://rsync.samba.org/features.html).

This doesn't really address any issues with your code, but I think rsync will be easier than trying to reinvent the wheel with SFTP.

Comment: Nope,as per my requirement I dont have to use any tool. I need to do it through scripts only.

Answer (score 0):

Rsync (or Unison) is best

Another solution would be to use `find`

```
 find . -name 'mad_*' -newer last_update -exec sftp ... {} \;
 touch last_update
```